# How do you draw objects that do not have texture with objects that have texture OPENGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I have several objects without texture coordinates UV passed into the fragment shader, and i only have two other objects with texture coordinates UV passed into the fragment shader. The objects without texture were still visible but with a dull color. But after plugging in the light equations it becomes black and non-visible. How do i draw the non-texturized objects without changing it's original color and also keeping the light equation (i've already created color arrays for them and passed them into the vertex shader). I've tried this but my fragment shader wouldn't compile.

```
#version 330 

  in vec3 fragmentColor;
  in vec3 fragmentNormal;
  in vec2 UV;
  in vec4 Position;
  uniform vec4 lighteye;
  uniform float intensityh;
  uniform float intensityd;
  uniform float objectd;
  uniform vec4 worldCoord;
```

// Data for the texture
    uniform sampler2D texture_Colors;

```
if(UV.x >= 0.0)
color = intensityh * texture2D( texture_Colors, UV ).rgb * diffuse + (intensityd * texture2D( texture_Colors, UV ).rgb * something) ;
else
color = vec4(fragmentColor,1.0);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and write your entire shaders in it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you could do something like this:

```
color r = intensityh * texture2D( texture_Colours, worldCoord.xy).rgb * diffuse+( intensityd* texture2D (texture_Colours, worldCoord.xy).rgb * something
```

This should texture your objects based on their position in the 3D space. **Don't forget, however, to enable texture repeating by CPU code for each texture, like this:**

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: I did it with the worldCoord.xy and it only gives me a single color. The UV coordinates are for texture.

Comment: @simon Since you said that not all objects have UV coordinates, something based on the fragments' position has to be used instead. I'll try to think a bit more about it.

Comment: @simon What does Position mean in your code? Screen coordinates or World coordinates?

Comment: World coordinates are the eye to world . Position is the multiplication of View matrix with the vertices points

Comment: @simon Try to use Position.xy instead of worldCoord.xy in the answer above, then.